# How to assign ordinality to text, for the purpose of grouping data in Access report

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I want to group an Access report base on a custom grouping (as oppose by alphabet descending or ascending)

for example:

**Proposal Phase**

data...

**Discovery Phase**

data...

**Identification Phase**

data...

right now,with only order by alphabet , it shows Proposal -> Identification -> Discovery, or vice versa.

I could assign numbers to the text itself, such as  1.Proposal, 2.Discovery, 3.Identification. but i'd like to avoid that.
Is there a feature in Access that allows me to assign ordinality , sort of like factors for R?

Answer (score 2):

add another numeric column, name it position or rank...  sort by this column.  That's the only way you can achieve this.